# Как подключиться к MS SQL с помощью ASP?

Tags: asp, sql-server

Прошу помощи.
Требуется в очень сжатые сроки разодраться с технологией ASP и Microsoft SQL.

В наличие есть Microsoft SQL Server 2008 и Visual Studio 2010.
Приведите пример подключения к БД и выборки данных из нее. И, если есть, ссылочки на туторы.

ДЛЯ САМЫХ УМНЫХ:
В Googl'e уже был.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connectionString1" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\db1.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Код VB.NET:

```
Dim myConnStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connectionString1").ConnectionString
Dim cnn As New SqlConnection(myConnStr)

Dim selectCommand As New SqlCommand("SELECT * from table1 WHERE p1=@p1Value and p2=@p2Value", cnn)
selectCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@p1Value", _
           SqlDbType.SmallInt)).Value = CType(100, Integer)    'установка значения типа соотв. в БД
selectCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@p2Value", _
           SqlDbType.Real)).Value = CType(10.5, Double)
cnn.Open()

Dim dataReader As SqlDataReader
dataReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
If dataReader.HasRows Then
    Try
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        While dataReader.Read
            'dataReader.Item(j)     'очередная строка, Item(j) - j номер столбца, можно обращаться по имени столбца
            i += 1
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
Else
End If
dataReader.Close()
cnn.Close()
```

Могут быть синтаксические ошибки.